# Porque quando escrevo na div ela muda de posição?

Tags: css, html5

Escrevo algo em uma das `<div>` e ela muda de posição. Porque?

Aqui isso acontecendo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JHIjB

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "wrap1">
   <div>algo</div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,html{
   height:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
.wrap1{
   min-height:100%; 
   background: #e1e1e1;
}
.wrap1 div{
   min-width: 45%;
   height:300px;
   min-height:50%;
   margin: 10px;
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background: #b0bec5;
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: o porquê eu não sei, já que não mecho com CSS, mas adicionando ao texto uma position:absolute curiosamente funcionou aqui, olha esse patch que fiz: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AmaDd

Comment: Por favor, coloque seu código aqui. Se o codepen desaparece a pergunta não fará sentido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom agora que entendi sua pergunta vou te explicar:

Primeiro isso acontece por causa do **inline-block**, ele se comporta conforme o conteúdo da página. Tente adicionar conteúdos fora da **DIV** e você entenderá isso. Exemplo abaixo:

```
display:inline-block;

<div class = "wrap1">
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Segundo **inline-block** é diferente do **block**, o **block** se comporta colocando-se um acima do outro. O **inline-block** é bem especifico para isso, ajustar-se conforme todo o conteúdo dá página, se não, na mesma linha.

Na prática usamos o valor inline-block quando queremos definir um valor para a propriedade width. Sob certas circunstâncias, alguns navegadores ignoram a propriedade **width** para elementos **inline**, então definindo display: **inline-block** para tais elementos você forçará o navegador a reconhecer o valor definido para a propriedade **width**.

Comment: A pergunta é porque acontece isso e não a forma de solucionar.

Comment: Entendeu @JorgeB.?

Comment: +1 pela edição para a nova resposta.

Comment: +1 pelo +1 :P!!

Comment: Ei Jorge não vai colocar com certa a resposta?...Acho que não vai ser muito diferente outras respostas. :D

Comment: Quem fez a pergunta foi o Mario, não o @JorgeB. Só o Mario pode marcar a resposta como aceita. Ele pode estar esperando para ver se aparecem outras respostas, ou talvez não saiba como marcar a resposta como aceita. Mario: se estiver lendo isto, veja http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/

Comment: Valeu @bfavaretto!

Comment: Marquei como aceita, então parece ser uma característica do inline-block quando eu preencher todas as boxes esse problema deve sumir, embora eu ache isso estranho já sei que é coisa do desse display. Valeu!